Necessary and sufficient conditions for arbitrary union of subgroups to be a subgroup
Suppose I have a collection of subgroups $\{H_i\}$ of a group $G$ and I know that $\bigcup_i {H_i} = \langle \bigcup_i {H_i} \rangle$. What conditions can I infer about the subgroups? I am aware of conditions I can set on $\{H_i\}$ that will ensure their union is a subgroup (for instance, if for every $H_i,H_j$ there exists some $H_k$ such that $H_i < H_k$ and $H_j < H_k$, then $\bigcup_i {H_i} = \langle \bigcup_i {H_i} \rangle$), but I am wondering if there is a necessary and sufficient statement. I can't seem to prove the converse to the statement I provided above, for instance.

Related (sufficient condition). But there does not seem to exist a necessary and sufficient condition. https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=union+of+subgroups

Thank you, it seems this is a repeat. I'll close this question.
